# how to compile java files in linux with a package

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I am able to compile my Main.java file without any issues in Eclipse.

Inside Main.java I have

```java
package com.selenium.zLoadProfilerPkg;
```

Inside the other 3 files I also have

```java
package com.selenium.zLoadProfilerPkg;
```

However when I upload the whole structure to linux, and I try to compile it, I get errors:

```
[sgalkov@zpub zLoadProfilerPkg]$ pwd
/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg
[sgalkov@zpub zLoadProfilerPkg]$ cd /home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg/; javac -cp ".:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-java-2.30.0.jar:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/libs/*:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7-sources.jar:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/lib/*:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg" Main.java
Main.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    BrowsermobProxy bmp = new BrowsermobProxy(PROXY_API_HOST, PROXY_API_PORT);
    ^
symbol:   class BrowsermobProxy
location: class Main

Main.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    BrowsermobProxy bmp = new BrowsermobProxy(PROXY_API_HOST, PROXY_API_PORT);
                              ^
symbol:   class BrowsermobProxy
location: class Main

Main.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
        HarStorage hs = new HarStorage(HARSTORAGE_HOST, HARSTORAGE_PORT);
        ^
symbol:   class HarStorage
location: class Main

Main.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
        HarStorage hs = new HarStorage(HARSTORAGE_HOST, HARSTORAGE_PORT);
                            ^
symbol:   class HarStorage
location: class Main

4 errors
[sgalkov@zpub zLoadProfilerPkg]$
```

If I comment out "package com.selenium.zLoadProfilerPkg;" in each of the 4 files and compile them one by one, everything works fine.

Also, If I try to compile it this way:

```bsh
cd /home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg/;

javac -cp ".\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-java-2.30.0.jar\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/libs/*\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7-sources.jar\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/lib/*\
:/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg" \
BrowsermobProxy.java HarStorage.java HttpRequest.java Main.java
```

it does compile but I am getting an extra class for Main.java

```
 rw-r--r-- 1 sgalkov users  1422 Mar 11 20:30 Main$1.class
 rw-r--r-- 1 sgalkov users  8264 Mar 11 20:30 Main.class
 rw-r--r-- 1 sgalkov users 14864 Mar 11 19:32 Main.java
```

and I am unable to run the program, I get the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg/Main)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

I've looked around and tried various options but can't get this project to compile and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Main$1.class is not an "extra" class, it's an inner class (usually). Do you have an inner class in Main.java? (Even an anonymous inner class?)

Comment: Also you'd typically write a small script to handle the classpath and such if you need to build this on a regular basis in a *nix shell. Or you could use ant/maven/etc. Another alternative (if you aren't building it regularly on *nix) would be to just (cough) export it from Eclipse (since you say it works in Eclipse, export as a JAR). Exporting from an IDE Is not a good habit to get into, but if you need to do it on a one-off or very infrequent basis it works.

Comment: thanks I found the inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
dir=/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler

cd "$dir/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/"

javac -cp ".\
:$dir/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-java-2.30.0.jar\
:$dir/selenium-2.30.0/libs/*\
:$dir/selenium-2.30.0/selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar\
:$dir/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7-sources.jar\
:$dir/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7/lib/*\
:$dir/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler/src/" \
com/selenium/zLoadProfilerPkg/*.java
```

Comment: this works but I am still getting a Main$1.class file for some reason

Comment: sometimes the shortest answer is the best because Genius is simplicity :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile your application outside of an IDE you should use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org).  Here's an example build.xml file which you could use to compile your application with Ant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler/zLoadProfiler/zLoadProfiler"
    default="compile">

<property name="dir.prefix" value="/home/sgalkov/zpp_tech_git_checkout/profiler"/>

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <pathelement location="classes"/>
    <fileset dir="${dir.prefix}/selenium-2.30.0">
        <include name="selenium-java-2.30.0.jar"/>
        <include name="libs/*"/>
        <include name="selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${dir.prefix}/browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7">
        <include name="browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-7-sources.jar"/>
        <include name="lib/*"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<property name="compile.classpath" refid="compile.classpath"/>


<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="classes"/>
    <javac failonerror="true" srcdir="src" debug="yes"
        includes="**/*.java" destdir="classes"
        classpath="${compile.classpath}">
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="classes"/>
</target>

</project>
```

All your classes will end up in a folder called `classes` with a structure that mirrors your source package hierarchy.  To execute your application, you can just place the `classes` folder in your classpath and call your main class as `com.selenium.zLoadProfilerPkg.Main`.  There's some nice features in ant such as packaging your classes in a jar file, etc.  Check it out.

As far as the `Main$1.class`, be sure your package definitions are correctly defined at the top of each of your java source files.

Also, be sure to check the `compile.classpath` in the ant build script I provided to ensure I didn't mispell or represent something from the classpath you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start **javac** in the source root directory where there is a subdirectory `com` (the top package). This you can test on Windows too.

You might deploy the compiled .class'es / jars / wars / ears too. Then the target of compilation is needed (1.5, 1.6, 1.7).

And yes, **ant** or nowadays **maven** might provide a good build infrastructure, both inside the IDE and standalone.

Comment: yes I agree, ant/maven are a good idea but I'm just trying to get this work first :)